# World Coordinates to Texture Coordinates

Tags: c#, math, 3d, terrain

I am working on a terrain editor for my game and currently on the texture painting part.

My terrain is chunked in chunksizes of 32, and each chunk has a "layer" texture with the scale of 128

So my problem is that I have these variables

```
public int ChunkSize = 32;
public int LayerTextureSize = 128;
```

What I need to do is to transform from the a point in the world I get from raycasting to the point on the texture, This was easy when i had LayerTextureSize the same as ChunkSize as then I could just do

```
var hit = Raycast(MousePos);
var chunkX = (int) (hit.x / (TerrainGlobals.ChunkSize));
var chunkY = (int) (hit.y / (TerrainGlobals.ChunkSize));

var pixelPosX = hit.x % (TerrainGlobals.ChunkSize);
var pixelPosY = hit.y % (TerrainGlobals.ChunkSize);
ApplyTexture(chunkX, chunkY, pixelPosX, pixelPosY);
```

Though when the LayerTextureSize is bigger then ChunkSize it will just draw in the corner. 
In the code above I do not user LayerTextureSize, as here its assumed that the layersize is the same as the chunksize

Comment: Not an expert, but  you mention raycasting, while the code  seems to be a mapping.

Comment: Raycasting is how I get the worldPosX and worldPosY, updated main post a bit

Comment: 1 more thing to improve the question: It is not shown how LayerTextureSize is used, so we are left to assume it is used in certain way. Could you please elaborate more?